# How to unblock as mvn cli stuck indefinitely on ubuntu?

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

maven command executed : mvn clean install -X

Combination of java and maven tried on both ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 16.04:

1. mvn:3.6.3 && java 11.0.*
2. mvn:3.6.3 && java 17.0.*
3. mvn 3.8.6 && java 17.0.*

It is a simple hello world project which compiles normally on a windows 10. There is no problem with java as i am able to run the windows generated jar in ubuntu without any issue.

Getting thread dump is difficult as the jcmd or jstack return after few seconds with failure to connect with the jvm. BUt managed to get this one from multiple attempts.

```
> 2022-07-09 05:38:30 Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
> (17.0.1+12-LTS-39 mixed mode, sharing):
> 
> Threads class SMR info:
> _java_thread_list=0x00007ff544157400, length=13, elements={ 0x00007ff59c023aa0, 0x00007ff59c163600, 0x00007ff59c1649e0,
> 0x00007ff59c16c910, 0x00007ff59c16dcc0, 0x00007ff59c16f0d0,
> 0x00007ff59c170a80, 0x00007ff59c171fb0, 0x00007ff59c173420,
> 0x00007ff59c19aae0, 0x00007ff59c19e4b0, 0x00007ff554000d30,
> 0x00007ff544156560 }
> 
> "main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=9513.35ms elapsed=10.10s
> tid=0x00007ff59c023aa0 nid=0xb5f runnable  [0x00007ff5a1d53000]   
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>         at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor.interpolate(StringVisitorModelInterpolator.java:1455)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor.visit(StringVisitorModelInterpolator.java:789)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor.visit(StringVisitorModelInterpolator.java:664)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor.visit(StringVisitorModelInterpolator.java:621)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor.visit(StringVisitorModelInterpolator.java:675)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor.visit(StringVisitorModelInterpolator.java:264)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator.interpolateModel(StringVisitorModelInterpolator.java:107)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.interpolateModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:859)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:417)
>         at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
>         at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:293)
>         at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:538)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:523)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:410)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
>         at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:165)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:404)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:374)
>         - locked <0x000000008e8fa010> (a org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:234)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:105)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
>         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
>         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
>         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
>         at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@17.0.1/Native
> Method)
>         at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@17.0.1/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
>         at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@17.0.1/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@17.0.1/Method.java:568)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
> 
> "Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=3.11ms
> elapsed=9.67s tid=0x00007ff59c163600 nid=0xb66 waiting on condition 
> [0x00007ff581513000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>         at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@17.0.1/Native
> Method)
>         at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@17.0.1/Reference.java:253)
>         at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@17.0.1/Reference.java:215)
> 
> "Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=3.99ms elapsed=9.67s
> tid=0x00007ff59c1649e0 nid=0xb67 in Object.wait() 
> [0x00007ff580bfe000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object
> monitor)
>         at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.1/Native Method)
>         - waiting on <0x0000000080084688> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>         at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@17.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
>         - locked <0x0000000080084688> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>         at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@17.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
>         at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@17.0.1/Finalizer.java:172)
> 
> "Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=3.25ms
> elapsed=9.62s tid=0x00007ff59c16c910 nid=0xb68 waiting on condition 
> [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> 
> "Service Thread" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=2.11ms elapsed=9.61s
> tid=0x00007ff59c16dcc0 nid=0xb69 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]   
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> 
> "Monitor Deflation Thread" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=1.28ms
> elapsed=9.61s tid=0x00007ff59c16f0d0 nid=0xb6a runnable 
> [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> 
> "C2 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=6674.30ms
> elapsed=9.61s tid=0x00007ff59c170a80 nid=0xb6b runnable 
> [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE    Compiling:
> 2307   !   4      
> org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$1::interpolate
> (97 bytes)
> 
> "C1 CompilerThread0" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=5473.14ms
> elapsed=9.61s tid=0x00007ff59c171fb0 nid=0xb6c runnable 
> [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE    Compiling:
> 2309       3      
> org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor::visit
> (205 bytes)
> 
> "Sweeper thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.36ms elapsed=9.61s
> tid=0x00007ff59c173420 nid=0xb6d runnable  [0x0000000000000000]   
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> 
> "Notification Thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.55ms
> elapsed=9.58s tid=0x00007ff59c19aae0 nid=0xb6e runnable 
> [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> 
> "Common-Cleaner" #12 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=2.51ms elapsed=9.55s
> tid=0x00007ff59c19e4b0 nid=0xb70 in Object.wait() 
> [0x00007ff571dfb000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on
> object monitor)
>         at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.1/Native Method)
>         - waiting on <0x0000000080084940> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>         at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@17.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
>         - locked <0x0000000080084940> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>         at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@17.0.1/CleanerImpl.java:140)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@17.0.1/Thread.java:833)
>         at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@17.0.1/InnocuousThread.java:162)
> 
> "Attach Listener" #15 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=7.79ms elapsed=0.11s
> tid=0x00007ff554000d30 nid=0xb8e waiting on condition 
> [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> 
> "C2 CompilerThread1" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=46.73ms
> elapsed=0.06s tid=0x00007ff544156560 nid=0xb8f runnable 
> [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE    Compiling:
> 2273       4      
> org.apache.maven.model.interpolation.StringVisitorModelInterpolator$ModelVisitor::interpolate
> (11 bytes)
> 
> "VM Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=43.68ms elapsed=9.72s tid=0x00007ff59c15f740
> nid=0xb65 runnable
> 
> "GC Thread#0" os_prio=0 cpu=29.09ms elapsed=9.89s
> tid=0x00007ff59c062d30 nid=0xb60 runnable
> 
> "GC Thread#1" os_prio=0 cpu=26.29ms elapsed=7.01s
> tid=0x00007ff568005040 nid=0xb74 runnable
> 
> "GC Thread#2" os_prio=0 cpu=22.81ms elapsed=7.01s
> tid=0x00007ff568005a70 nid=0xb75 runnable
> 
> "GC Thread#3" os_prio=0 cpu=29.35ms elapsed=7.00s
> tid=0x00007ff5680064a0 nid=0xb76 runnable
> 
> "G1 Main Marker" os_prio=0 cpu=0.51ms elapsed=9.88s
> tid=0x00007ff59c074310 nid=0xb61 runnable
> 
> "G1 Conc#0" os_prio=0 cpu=0.39ms elapsed=9.88s tid=0x00007ff59c075270
> nid=0xb62 runnable
> 
> "G1 Refine#0" os_prio=0 cpu=0.85ms elapsed=9.86s
> tid=0x00007ff59c1313e0 nid=0xb63 runnable
> 
> "G1 Service" os_prio=0 cpu=7.63ms elapsed=9.86s tid=0x00007ff59c1322d0
> nid=0xb64 runnable
> 
> "VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=19.55ms elapsed=9.57s
> tid=0x00007ff59c19c690 nid=0xb6f waiting on condition
> 
> JNI global refs: 11, weak refs: 9
```

Comment: First check the version you are using via `mvn --version` and post the output....

Comment: How did you install and configure Java and Maven?   Does it work if you use the Maven (and JDK) available with `sudo apt install maven`?

Comment: Also, where does the build stall?  Does _anything_ get printed?

Comment: `mvn --version` : same result. Nothing gets printed.

Comment: `How did you install and configure Java and Maven` : 
java : installed using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04
mvn installed using : wget and copy manually under /opt and define /etc/environments. But same results with apt-get install maven

Comment: `Does anything get printed` : NOthing gets printed.

Comment: If `mvn —version` does not work, your JVM may be broken.  Does `java` and `java -version` work?

Comment: Do you have a MAVEN_OPTS environment variable defined? Can you run a small HelloWorld.java program?

Comment: 'Do you have a MAVEN_OPTS environment variable defined'
@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen


[genrica@genrica:/buildstore/my-app/src/main/java$ javac com/mycompany/app/App.java]

[genrica@genrica:/buildstore/my-app/src/main/java$ java com.mycompany.app.App]
Hello World!`        

`genrica@genrica:/buildstore/my-app/src/main/java$ echo $M2_HOME
/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3`         

`genrica@genrica:/buildstore/my-app/src/main/java$ echo $M2
$M2_HOME/bin`        
 
`genrica@genrica:/buildstore/my-app/src/main/java$ which mvn
/usr/bin/mvn`

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

[echo $MAVEN_OPTS]

-Xmx2048m -Xms256m

Comment: This is most likely the reason. Why did you set it to this value?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying out as this took lot of time but no results.

Now i installed ubuntu ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso instead of a server iso. After that i installed default-jre-11-headless followed by apt-get install maven.

Now all mvn command works as it is supposed to be.
java version : openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19

mvn version : Apache Maven 3.6.3

Comment: This confirms that it was a configuration issue (and not a hardware problem or something like that). You should install openjdk-11-jdk to get full tooling so maven can compile things.

Comment: looks like that. ALso i think there was some issue in reaching out http/https urls. And the connection would just hang there and not return until i killed the process? Now as the root-cause is not clear, i have to deploy all my vm with ubuntu-desktop instead of server.  Is there any clue from what i have updated so far. i do not want to replace servers with desktop.

Comment: Where did MAVEN_OPTS come from?

Comment: MAVEN_OPTS  is empty @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: Yes. Now.  It wasn’t before